# Custom implementation of KNN regression

Tags: regression, python, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm attempting to implement KNN from first principles.
Given the dataset with training values where the format is
training features -> training outputs and contains dataset :

```
1,1 -> 1
2,2 -> 2
3,3 -> 3
```

Are my steps below correct?

Calculate all distances between each of the points in the dataset:

```
Distance between [1 1] and [1 1] : 0.0
Distance between [1 1] and [2 2] : 1.414
Distance between [1 1] and [3 3] : 2.828
Distance between [2 2] and [1 1] : 1.414
Distance between [2 2] and [2 2] : 0.0
Distance between [2 2] and [3 3] : 1.414
Distance between [3 3] and [1 1] : 2.828
Distance between [3 3] and [2 2] : 1.414
Distance between [3 3] and [3 3] : 0.0
```

To determine which class a new instance belongs to take the average of the nearest K neighbors.

For example, if a new instance is [3,5] then:

```
Distance between [3, 5] and [1, 1] : 4.472
Distance between [3, 5] and [2, 2] : 3.162
Distance between [3, 5] and [3, 3] : 2.0
```

As K=2 the nearest K points are [2, 3] and [3, 3].

The classifications for [2, 3] and [3, 3] are [2, 3].

Taking the average of [2,3] = 2.5.

Therefore for  [3,5] it's predicted values is  2.5

Comment: What is your question? If you're looking for code review, this is not the best place for such question.

Comment: @Tim I've updated the question.